# SQL select if count on relation is greater than X?

Tags: mysql, sql, count

I have 2 tables

"**orders**" has 1-to-N relation with "**articles**"

```
SELECT `orders`.* FROM `orders` INNER JOIN `articles` ON 
`articles`.`orders_id` = `orders`.`id` where ????
```

How can I make a sub-count on articles and get only orders with 4 or more articles?

Thanks you for help!

Comment: have you tried group by and having?

Comment: Please provide your table data and attr

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this as:

```
SELECT o.*
FROM orders o INNER JOIN
     articles a
     ON a.orders_id = o.id
GROUP BY o.id
HAVING COUNT(*) >= 4;
```

This is even a legitimate use of `SELECT *` with `GROUP BY`, because `o.id` is (presumably) the primary key on `orders`.

Another method is:

```
select o.*
from orders o
where (select count(*)
       from articles a
       where a.order_id = o.id
      ) >= 4;
```

This has the advantage that it can use an index on `articles(order_id)`, so it can have better performance.

Answer (score 3):

Use aggregation with a filter on aggregated result by using `HAVING` clause

```
SELECT `o`.*
FROM `orders`  o
INNER JOIN `articles`  a
ON `a`.`orders_id` = `o`.`id`
GROUP BY o.id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT a.id) >=4
```